# Loading dynamic images as background, how can I check for image first?

Tags: apex, visualforce, css, outputpanel

I am using dynamic images as the background image of a div in a visual force page I am working on. I apply the background to my div in CSS as follows:

```
background-image:url({!URLFOR($Action.Attachment.Download, AttachmentId)})
```

However there may not be an image available and when there is not then the VisualForce page crashes. I have figured out how to check it properly and use a default image when I am putting the image into an img tag as follows:

```
<apex:outputPanel rendered="{!!StaticImage}"> 
     <img src="{!URLFOR($Action.Attachment.Download, AttachmentId)}"/>
</apex:outputPanel>
<apex:outputPanel rendered="{!StaticImage}">
     <img src="{!DefaultImageName}" />
</apex:outputPanel>
```

My issue is that I don't know how or if it is even possible to apply this type of check to the background property in CSS instead of to an img tag?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried something like

```
background-image:url({!IF(ISBLANK(AttachmentId),
    StaticImage,
    URLFOR($Action.Attachment.Download, AttachmentId))
})
```

?

(I didn't try it plus it might require some extra apostrophes/quote signs to work!)

There's a chance URLFOR doesn't like to be conditionally used like that. But then you should still be able to write equivalent if-else in the Apex (if you have a controller extension there): [How to specify an Action for an URLFOR in apex](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/24797/how-to-specify-an-action-for-an-urlfor-in-apex)

Ugliest scenario to get it to work would be to hardcode the link:

```
IF(ISBLANK(AttachmentId), StaticImage, '/servlet/servlet.FileDownload?file=' + AttachmentId)
```